# #Unity Profiler shows rendering time increases by a lot on Android device? (Pixel 3)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gpu, render, profiler

I have a simple scene (show as below) with only one object
[image]

I want to test FPS on Android so I made a build and turned on profiler.
[image]

FPS was stable at 30 for about 10min and the then dropped to 17. Profiler shows that GFX.presentframe suddenly took very long

Any idea what's happening? Or is there a way I can dig further? This is on a pixel phone

Comment: Take a look at logcat, usually this is caused by overheat or battery saving.

Comment: thank you! I figured it out. It's indeed caused by overheating. I am using a Pixel phone which has a very low threshold for heat throttle